# Как получить ID роли, которая была упомянута в команде?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно получить ID роли командой, но никак не могу разобраться как это сделать.

Пример:

```
!getrole @role
```

А в коде я должен это упоминание конвертировать в ID роли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@commands.command()
async def getrole(self, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.send(role.id)
```

```
@bot.command()
async def getrole(role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.send(role.id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]